# Installing GNU Radio with pybombs, Cannot find a source URI for package python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnuradio, centos6.5

I'm trying to get gnu radio installed on a virtual machine.  The VM is CentOS 6.5.  I used the a vagrant box for 64bit Centos 6.5 Minimal.  CentOS 6.5 already has python 2.6 and it's unwise to change the default python because yum and other packages depend on it.  I installed python 2.7 alongside it because I'm trying to use pybombs to install gnuradio.

Here are the changes I've made to the virtual machine in an attempt to download gnuradio:

```
su -
yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'
yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel xz-libs wget
```

I downloaded python 2.7, unzipped, and placed in shared directory
cd to python2.7 directory

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make altinstall

yum install epel-release

curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py

pip2.7 install --upgrade setuptools
pip2.7 install PyBOMBS
pybombs recipes add gr-recipes git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes.git

pybombs recipes add gr-etcetera git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-etcetera.git

pybombs prefix init /usr/local -a myprefix

pybombs -p /usr/local install gnuradio
```

This is the error I get:

```
PyBombs.install - INFO - Installing package: python
PyBombs.Packager.source - WARNING - Cannot find a source URI for package python
PyBombs.install - ERROR - Error installing package python. Aborting.
```

Pybombs successfully installed a few other packages before reaching this error. I'm not sure how to fix it - I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you mean python **2**.6, right?

Comment: Yeah, I did mean to write that centos comes with python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

I created the setup script for python 2.7 and CentOS 5.x. I think you can use it for CentOs 6.x:
https://github.com/weldpua2008/python-2.7.x-on-Centos-5.x/blob/master/install_python27.sh

Comment: I ran the shell script and it appears to have successfully installed python 2.7 on my centos vm.  However, when I run pybombs, I'm still getting the same error at the same point.